# grep from a substring to find the match string

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have an array of substring

```
    @substringarray = ('12347', '12357', '123467', '123488')
```

Then I have a value of a full string to find out

```
    $fullstring = '123477777777';
```

How can I use it to find the match with It should return `12347`

I want something like this:

```
    @testsa = grep( /^$fullstring/, @substringarray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short way, **TMTOWTDI**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @substringarray = ('12347', '12357', '123467', '123488');
my $fullstring = '123477777777';

print for grep { $fullstring =~ m/^$_/ } @substringarray;
```

##### Output

```
12347
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it the wrong way around - your full string isn't going to be in any of the shorter substrings, is it?

One way is to turn your list of substrings into a regular expression that matches any of them, and test the full string against it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my @substringarray = ('12347', '12357', '123467', '123488');
my $fullstring = '123477777777';

# Make sure to escape any characters in the strings that are special in REs
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @substringarray;

if ($fullstring =~ /$re/) {
  say "Found a match: $&";
} else {
  say 'No matches found.'
}
```

Another way, nice if you're going to be matching the substrings against a lot of different inputs, or want to find all matches, is to use the [`Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS), which provides very efficient simultaneous searching for multiple substrings:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS;

my @substringarray = ('12347', '12357', '123467', '123488');
my $fullstring = '123477777777';

my $ac = Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS->new(\@substringarray);

if (my $match = $ac->first_match($fullstring)) {
  say "Found a match: $match";
} else {
  say 'No matches found.'
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question, how does this `Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS->new(\@substringarray);` works if `substringarray` is array of object?, lets say `%substringarray;` `$substringarray->{12344} ='info 1'`, `$substringarray->{12345} = 'info 2'`

Comment: @AlKasih It needs an arrayref of strings to build a matching automata. So you'd have to figure out a way to map your objects to strings to look for.

Comment: I just need to change the `\@substringarray` ? But still able to use the `Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS` ?

Comment: Or this `Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS` just able to work with array?

Comment: I will accept this as answer if you can give more sample to arrayref, please.

Comment: @AlKasih The constructor takes a single argument, an arrayref of the strings to search for. If you're unfamiliar with references in perl, start with https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut and https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc

Comment: I just dont want to do a loop

Comment: `my %subset = map { $_ => $hash{$_} }  grep { $fullstring =~ m/^$_/ } keys %hash;`

Answer (score 2):

You got your variable backwards!

You're checking if the substring starts with $fullstring.

You want to check if $fullstring starts with the substring.

It's just a question of swapping the two variables.

```perl
my @testsa = grep( $fullstring =~ /^\Q$_/, @substringarray );
```